# Can I setup ubuntu to use more ram, currently having 12GB of ram?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ram, caching

On windows machine which I use for development purpose, I did use some software like primocache which cache the disk and the files are loaded from ram (if I setup the drive). This way my program is loading in second and things going a little faster.

Now I have ubuntu in my system (no dual boot). I see it's only consuming 3GB out of 12GB. Is ubuntu use the other ram part to cache the thing like SuperFetch (sysMain) does in Windows 10. Did I need to setup anything or ubuntu is clever enough to take the ram that I am not using for cache the things.

Are these ram going to wasted or I am just thinking the wrong way. Someone confirm that Ubuntu use extra ram for cache the stuff (Like Superfetch)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your filesystem and how it implements caching. Comparing with Windows is not all that useful, because Windows is all NTFS, whereas in Linux you might choose to use one of the `ext` systems (`ext2`, `ext3`, or `ext4`), or `xfs`, `btrfs`, `zfs`, or any of the others.

The newer versions of Ubuntu are allowing experimental installation of the system using `zfs`, and the cahing system of `zfs` (the ARC or Adaptive Replacement Cache) is fantastic, and will [soon get better with persistence between boot-ups](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/02/zfs-on-linux-should-get-a-persistent-ssd-read-cache-feature-soon/).

A word of warning, though, as of now (Ubuntu 19.10 and daily images of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), `zfs` on boot drive is considered strictly an experimental feature, with no guarantees or support.

Comment: You clearly didn’t bother to google the words in the question. The OP is talking about SuperFetch’s application prefetching. You can probably implement that on Linux using the readahead() system call after tracing previous app startups, but AFAIK no distro has implemented this. It has little to do with the filesystem’s read ahead cache. BTW persistent ARC will not do this. That’s a much lower level thing.

Comment: Easy enough to say a year and a half later, when you also didn't bother to answer the question. Turns out it is much easier to criticize than to provide a helpful answer.